# Create json structure in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to create a json structure like this in Android but cannot find any way to complete it.

```
{
  "FirstName": Fred,
  "LastName": "Poulsen",
  "Age": "18",
  "Phone": {
    "mobile": {}
  }
}
```

This is what I have tried to do.

```
        Map<Object, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Object, Object> phone = new HashMap<>();


        objectMap.put("FirstName", "Fred");
        objectMap.put("LastName", "Poulsen");
        objectMap.put("Age", "18");
        objectMap.put("Phone", phone);
        input.put("mobile", body);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `Gson` to make your json. Add `Gson` dependency `app/build.gradle`, create `User` class. Try this

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("FirstName")
    private String mFirstName;

    @SerializedName("LastName")
    private String mLastName;

    @SerializedName("Age")
    private int mAge;

    @SerializedName("Phone")
    private Phone mPhone;

    public class Phone {
        @SerializedName("mobile")
        private String mobile;

        public Phone(String mobile) {
            this.mobile = mobile;
        }
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String phone) {
        mFirstName = firstName;
        mLastName = lastName;
        mAge = age;
        mPhone = new Phone(phone);
    }
}
```

```
new Gson().toJson(new User("Fred", "Poulsen", 18, "0123456789")); // your json
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the perfect structure will be :

```
    Map<Object, Object> phone = new HashMap<>();
    phone.put("mobile","1234567890");

    Map<Object, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
    objectMap.put("FirstName", "Fred");
    objectMap.put("LastName", "Poulsen");
    objectMap.put("Age", "18");
    objectMap.put("Phone", phone);
```

You can get mobile number using edittext.getText().toString().trim() and can add validation and then you can use this method easily.

Answer (score 0):

test it

```
  JSONObject jsonParent = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject jsonMobile = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonMobile.put("mobile","");
            jsonParent.put("FirstName", "Fred");
            jsonParent.put("LastName", "Poulsen");
            jsonParent.put("Age", "18");
            jsonParent.put("Phone", jsonMobile);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```